# How do I setup webhooks in Google Calendar to notify the users x minutes before the event?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to notify users (after they authorize) of their Calendar event `x` minutes before the event starts. The one similar to the push notification we get on web and mobile apps which says "Your event is going to start in 10 min".

I've gone through and have also experimented with [Calendar Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) but I found that I'm receiving the create/update/delete event information as callback but not the `x` minutes reminder information.

I'm not sure if Google Calendar exposes such API or the application itself should track the events which are going to start in next `x` min.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Push notification is for Event creation, change, cancellation, Attendee response and Agenda. Use [Reminders](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders), these are alarms triggered at a specified time before an event starts.

> The delivery methods offered by Google Calendar are:
>
> - **Pop-up**. These are supported on mobile platforms and on web clients.
> - **Email** sent by the server.
> - **SMS**. These are only available for G Suite customers.